# Minimal-size extending set in a directed graph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a directed graph, i.e. $V$ is a finite set and $E\subseteq V\times V$.

We call a subset $J\subseteq V$ **extending** if for every $v\in V\setminus J$ there is a directed path from some vertex $j\in J$ to $v$.

Is there a polynomial-time algorithm to find an extending subset of minimal size?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a linear time algorithm.

Contract all strongly connected components, then you get a DAG.
Find all the source vertex in the DAG. For each source vertex in the DAG, pick a single vertex from the strongly connected component represented by the source vertex.